# Angular - identify scss file by class name

Tags: angular, sass

I'm using angular 5 app with styles that are encapsulated into components.

If one runs `ng serve` command all styles will be inserted into `<styles>` tags into `<head>` part of the page. So in browser devtools I just see something like `.my-classname[_ngcontent-c25]` with no reference to it scss file where it is defined.

Is there any way to detect in which component this classname is defined?

Comment: Time ago, I read that it's impossible to determinate. I try to find the article where I had read it

Comment: Btw you can disable view encapsulation [setting it to `none`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) in order to have a predictable output. Be careful: you could encounter conflicts on your style

Answer (score 1):

You could run ng serve -sm -ec to see the source map. But there is a bug in the latest Angular CLI. But in [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9099) you will be able to find a workaround.

Comment: So, have you managed to make it work? I'm trying with 1.7.4 angular-cli version, tried to patch `node_modules@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\common.js` by adding `devtool: 'source-map'`, but no luck yet...

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#inspecting-generated-css):

> The exact values of these attributes aren't important. They are automatically generated and you never refer to them in application code.

There's no way to predict what will be the output and how stable it will be. Even if you apply a rule to a *generated class* there's no warranty it will be the same in next builds, since little changes can provocate huge differences in how style is generated.

If you want to apply an external style (not built inside the Angular building process), you could workaround it setting:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Inside your component. In this way, the output will be stable and predictable, but it opens the door to CSS conflicts.

Comment: Well, that's true that the attribute isn't really important. But sourcemaps would be quite handy. Check out Rukshan answer...

Comment: Yes but it's not a standard solution. In next versions of Angular the support can be dropped

Comment: Well, maybe... but so far according to angular-cli documentation  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds they could be enabled by using `--sourcemaps` key...